# use delta in loop_control label while ansible.builtin.shell

Tags: ansible

I have the simple ansible script as following.

I'm wondering if we can use `ansible.builtin.shell`'s `delta` in the `loop_control`?

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: echo {{ item[0] }} {{ item[1] }} {{ item[2] }}
      with_nested:
        - ['700', '600']
        - ['./5.csv', '5.xlsx']
        - [1, 2, 3, 4]
      loop_control:
        label: cmd-{{ item[0] }}-{{ item[1] }}-{{ item[2] }}-{{ the_delta_variable_produced_by_builtin_shell }}
```

Comment: See the answer. Do **not** comment on it if this is not what you want! Instead, [edit] your question and make it [mre]. E.g. where does the ``delta_var ...`` come from? A nested loop is redundant to reproduce the problem. So is the complexity of the label and argument of the command.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```yaml
    - command: "echo value_{{ item }}"
      register: result
      loop: [A, B, C]
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [command] ***************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=value_A)
changed: [localhost] => (item=value_B)
changed: [localhost] => (item=value_C)
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor change in your code. Register a var and use it in loop control:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: echo {{ item[0] }} {{ item[1] }} {{ item[2] }}
      register: result
      with_nested:
        - ['700', '600']
        - ['./5.csv', '5.xlsx']
        - [1, 2, 3, 4]
      loop_control:
        label: cmd-{{ item[0] }}-{{ item[1] }}-{{ item[2] }}-{{ result.delta }}
```

This produces what you want:

```
TASK [shell] ***************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-700-./5.csv-1-0:00:00.009238)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-700-./5.csv-2-0:00:00.007542)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-700-./5.csv-3-0:00:00.009125)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-700-./5.csv-4-0:00:00.009306)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-700-5.xlsx-1-0:00:00.007829)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-700-5.xlsx-2-0:00:00.008872)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-700-5.xlsx-3-0:00:00.007578)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-700-5.xlsx-4-0:00:00.007544)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-600-./5.csv-1-0:00:00.007417)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-600-./5.csv-2-0:00:00.008429)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-600-./5.csv-3-0:00:00.007245)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-600-./5.csv-4-0:00:00.007486)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-600-5.xlsx-1-0:00:00.009141)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-600-5.xlsx-2-0:00:00.008052)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-600-5.xlsx-3-0:00:00.008761)
changed: [localhost] => (item=cmd-600-5.xlsx-4-0:00:00.007917)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works. What's more,

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: echo zongzw
      register: z

    - debug: "msg={{z}}"
    - shell: echo {{ item[0] }} {{ item[1] }} {{ item[2] }}
      with_nested:
        - ['700', '600']
        - ['./5.csv', '5.xlsx']
        - [1, 2, 3, 4]
      loop_control:
        label: cmd-{{ item[0] }}-{{ item[1] }}-{{ item[2] }}-{{ result.delta }}
      register: result

    - debug: "msg={{ result }}"
```

By appending `- debug: "msg={{ result }}"`, it gathers and outputs the whole bunch of `result` produced from last step.

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "echo 700 ./5.csv 1",
                "delta": "0:00:00.006048",
                ...
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "700 ./5.csv 1",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "700 ./5.csv 1"
                ]
            },
            ...
```